# Importing gdalnumeric from osgeo - Python

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I am trying to import the gdalnumeric in order to use the function gdalnumeric.LoadFile(file) but I get the following error:

```
from . import _gdal_array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal_array: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

***UPDATE***:
When i try to install osgeo (through pip install gdal) and propably upgrade it , first i get the following error

```
Building wheel for osgeo (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully
```

then the next error is this

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for osgeo
  Running setup.py clean for osgeo
Failed to build osgeo
Installing collected packages: osgeo
  Running setup.py install for osgeo ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for osgeo did not run successfully
```

the thing is that i have the latest updates of pip as well as the setuptools

***UPDATE 2***

I forced re-installation of gdal by downloading the latest wheel and it worked!

Comment: Try `from osgeo import gdal_array`

Comment: @ahmadhanb the same error but when i import gdal there is no problem

Comment: @user2856 is it the same?? I think gdal.OpenEx is the same as gdal.Open

Comment: @user2856 as soon as I use the following ```ds.ReadAsArray()``` I get the error. My endgame is to get a panda dataframe

Comment: Then your GDAL is installed/configured incorrectly and you need to provide details about the installation.

Comment: @user2856 so when I install osgeo (i already have but it is upgrading it probably) i get a couple of errors that I will include in my question above

Comment: @user2856 i post the latest update i fixed it yeahhhh